# libcurl: ftp uploaded filename chopped off after # character

Tags: c, libcurl

I'm uploading a file to FTP using libcurl, using some simple example code.  The file is uploaded successfully, but the name I select is chopped off if I use the '#' character.

I call curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL, REMOTE_URL) with REMOTE_URL set to "ftp://myftp:soMePassWord@mywebsite.net/ABC#EFG.dat" but the output filename I see on the FTP is "ABC" (without extension).  The name always gets cut off after wherever the # character is positioned.

I'm using libcurl 7.21.7.0.

Comment: Not very sure..Just a thought, Should you use url encoding for `#`

Comment: That worked!  I used ABC%23EFG.dat instead, and now on the FTP it shows up as ABC#EFG.dat.  Now how do we convert your comment to an answer? :)

Comment: Good to hear It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to URL encode the `#` to `%23`.Because `#` identifies the beginning of a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

[From curl docs:](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTURL)

> Starting with version 7.20.0, the fragment part of the URI will not be sent as part of the path, which was previously the case.